# Preview.app thinks file is locked, Photoshop doesn't

Tags: disk-utility, permission, preview

Preview.app is acting really weird. Any picture I save, whether from Chrome or elsewhere, cannot be edited by Preview, but it can be edited by e.g. Photoshop.

1. I download the photo and save it to `~/Downloads/image.jpg`
   [image]
2. I double-click to open in Preview
   [image]
3. I crop it then try to save it
   [image]
4. Preview tells me the photo is locked and cannot be saved
   [image]
5. I tell it save anyway...
   [image]

I checked the permissions, xattr, and flags of all containing folders and of the file itself. No system/user lock flag is set. No weird xattr. The owner is me (matches with whoami). I have Read and Write permission on the containing folder and file.

```bash
-rw-r--r--@ 2 mehdi  staff  -   43K Aug 26 22:55 image.jpg
    com.apple.lastuseddate#PS     16B
    com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms     142B
    com.apple.quarantine      57B
```

I checked if the file is locked by another application with `lsof | grep filename.jpg", nothing aside from Preview.app and` filecoordinationd` appears. (not sure what the latter is for)

```bash
(base)  Downloads sudo lsof -V +c0 | grep "image.jpg"
filecoordinationd                         733                  root    9r      REG               1,15     44304            21208851 /Users/mehdisaffar/Downloads/image.jpg
Preview                                   850                 mehdi  txt       REG               1,15     44304            21208851 /Users/mehdisaffar/Downloads/image.jpg
```

I tried everything:

1. Repairing home permissions with Disk Utility
2. Repairing home permissions with Cocktail app
3. Repairing home permissions with CleanMyMac X
4. Repairing home permissions with Disk Utility in Recovery Mode
5. Reinstalling macOS (thinking Preview.app is corrupted)
6. Deleting savedState of Preview.app

Nothing works, no matter what picture I use! But Photoshop has no problem overwriting the file?

Comment: My first thought is that Preview doesn't have the rights to access where you're trying to safe the file.

Can you check the following link and see if it helps? It talks about control access to files and folders.

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/control-access-to-files-and-folders-on-mac-mchld5a35146/mac

Comment: @ErniePC12 I had given up on trying to fix it because it was incredibly frustrating and many things were broken, I don't remember what I did exactly but I re-reinstalled macOS or something like that.